# "Missing" glyphs in iTextSharp 5 AcroFields [PowerShell]

Tags: powershell, pdf, encoding, itext

I am using iTextSharp 5.5.13.2 in PowerShell - I'm trying to fill out a pdf form with pre-encoded string of characters, which will be read out as a Code128 barcode, after displaying it with a custom font. The template was made in Indesign and edited in Acrobat (pro), to provide properties such as text alignment, text size and font.

I am using the code below to fill out appropriate fields of the template:

```
    $pdfReader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader("path\to\template.pdf")
    $currentRecord = $kat7_List[$l]
    $currentId = $currentRecord.Split("`t")[0]
    $currentCode = $currentRecord.Split("`t")[1]
    $pdfStamper = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper($pdfReader, [System.IO.File]::Create("$($tempPath)\$($l).pdf"))

    $pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("id_Field", $currentId) | Out-Null
    $pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField("kod_Field", $currentCode) | Out-Null
    
    $pdfStamper.FormFlattening = 0
    $pdfStamper.Close()
    $pdfReader.Close()
```

The problem is that when I open the output file, the "kod_Field" AcroField is missing glyphs (Ò and Ó, 0210 and 0211 in Unicode chars) - which correspond to start and end characters in this particular Code128 representation, like pictured here:
[Barcode before clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwNFl.png)

When I click to edit it in Acrobat though, it suddenly regains these glyphs and the code is working (they are present in the font - I am using such system successfully in Indesign, with exactly the same encoded string values): [Barcode after clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LR6ii.png)

The coded strings are in UTF-16LE encoded text file, and should stay that way - I have tried setting BaseFont for the Stamper with BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, .CP1250 and .CP1252 - in either case the code came out even more "mangled" than now.

FormFlattening in the final version should be switched to true - I don't want open form fields in the final product. It flattens with missing glyphs, of course, but for testing purpose, I leave the flattening set to 0.

Which properties should I verify and what method governs encoding in this example? I though that .SetField() method should do the trick without much problem, since it's provided with properly encoded value. What might be the cause of such behavior?

Please help me out, regards.

--- Addendum, 17.08.2021 ---

I have temporarily changed the font to Myriad Pro in the template's kod_Field. It filled out properly, with no glyphs missing and proper string value. When I changed it back to code font via Acrobat in the finished pdf, it didn't have any missing glyphs. I really want to avoid using an additional operation (setting "textfont" property on the AcroField after setting the value) - because it should already be working "out of the box".

Comment: This question seems to be specific to [iTextSharp](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp), which is deprecated and has been replaced with [iText7](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet). Might be best to migrate to the newer library (and if you still have this problem, then you can open an issue for it on GitHub).

Comment: I have migrated my code to iText7 - the problem still persists, this time additionally the barcode is for some reason lower than intended. When field is clicked in an unflattened form - all glyphs are back to normal and the alignment comes back to center again. Either I am missing something about lack of basefont vs. pre-set AcroField or this really is a bug.

Comment: I would refer the honorable gentleman to my previous comment -- you can open an issue on GitHub for that project.

Comment: Hi, setting `font` for a form field is an expected way to fill out a form generally speaking.

Comment: @AlexeySubach Even if the font is already pre-set in the form field, and that aspect works when filling the field by hand?